# Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36B4

Tags: c#, exception, audio, windows-store-apps, media

i am getting this exception message `Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36B4` while using `MediaCapture` object from `Windows.Media.Capture` namespace. The exception occurs when i try to start recording the audio using the method `StartRecordToStreamAsync`. Here is my complete code

```
MediaCapture mediaCapture = new MediaCapture();
var capturesettings = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
capturesettings.StreamingCaptureMode = StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(capturesettings);
MediaEncodingProfile encodingProfile =
          MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp3(AudioEncodingQuality.Medium);
InMemoryRandomAccessStream iStream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
await mediaCapture.StartRecordToStreamAsync(encodingProfile, iStream);
```

Can some body can give me some hint that what i am doing wrong here? or what should i do to run it properly.

Thanks

Comment: `0xC00D36B4` is related to `MF_E_INVALIDMEDIATYPE` : "The data specified for the media type is invalid, inconsistent, or not supported by this object."

Comment: Hi, Did you find what was wrong in your code? can you please share?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `createMp3` is not supported yet.

> Note  While it is technically possible to call CreateMp3, you cannot
>   use this profile to transcode or encode audio into the MP3 format for
>   Windows Phone Store apps. This is because an MP3 encoder is not
>   shipped with Windows Phone. This API is included for completeness and
>   allows you to use it with 3rd party MP3 encoders that you include with
>   your app.

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.media.mediaproperties.mediaencodingprofile.createmp3.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow the example explained in this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn642092.aspx

I follow it to save a video from a webcam (changing the given code in a timely manner as you have already done by the code you've posted) and it works well.